# Why is the image of an algebraic group by a morphism also an algebraic group?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $K$ be a field and $G\subset K^m$ an (affine) algebraic group.

> If $\varphi:G\rightarrow (K^n,+)$ is a morphism of algebraic groups, why is $\varphi(G)$ is an algebraic group ?

I would say for instance that $\varphi(G)$ is constructible by Chevalleys Theorem (if $K$ is algebraically closed, isn't it ?), and a group so closed... hence an algebraic variety, but that seems to involve to much technicalities, and does not hold if $K$ is not algebraically closed (does it ?). A more direct way to see this ?

Comment: You are considering $K^n$ as an algebraic group with respect to addition?

Comment: @D_S Yes, as a first step !

Comment: If $K$ is not algebraically closed, you should be writing $\mathbb A^m_K$ in stead of $K^m$ everywhere.

Comment: @Remy The OP is most likely, if he's reading one of the standard books, basically thinking about all $K$-schemes as being $\overline{K}$-schemes with a (sufficiently nice) $G_K$-action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, Chevalley's theorem holds pretty universally—it holds for any morphism locally of finite presentation (or maybe you need actual finite presentation, I can't remember).

Anyways, the true reason is fairly sophisticated if you don't assume that your groups are smooth. The reference is then SGA 3 Proposition 1.2, Exposé VIB.

If your groups ARE smooth (which, for example, is always true in characteristic $0$), then, in fact any morphism $f:G\to H$ is a quotient map onto the scheme-theoretic image which is a smooth group scheme itself. The fact about it being a quotient map and smooth is just basic theory. The hard part is the [Closed Orbit Lemma](http://pages.uoregon.edu/brundan/math681fall07/notes4.pdf). See here for a (not too rigorous) discussion of the topic.

Comment: I am trying to understand basic algebraic geometry without getting into schemes yet, so still working with old fashionned polynomial maps !

Comment: @Drike The link that I gave discusses things in this fashion I believe :) Else try looking for the Closed Orbit Lemma in any of the classical texts (e.g. Borel).

Comment: Well Alex, actually many thanks for pointing at those notes to me, I am reading through all chapters and they are of great help !

Comment: Is 'here' in "See here …" referring to the link to "Closed Orbit Lemma" in the previous paragraph?

Comment: The link is dead