# Image of an algebraic group by a morphism and Chevalley.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $K$ be a non-algebraically closed field, and $\bf K$ an algebraic closure.

Consider $(G,+)\subset \mathbf G_a^n$ an affine algebraic group (the zero set of linear maps), and $$\alpha:G\rightarrow\mathbf G_a^m$$ a linear map. 
For example $G=K$ and the map $\alpha:K\longrightarrow K,\ x\mapsto x^p-x$.

> Is there (and why so) a linear map $L$ with coefficients in $K$ such that $$\alpha(G)=\big\{x\in K:L(x)=0\big\}$$ (assume $K$ has characteristic $p$ here otherwise it is easy : $\alpha(G)$ must be a $K$-vector space)

I believe it is given as the zero set of some polynomials with coffecients in $\mathbf K$ thanks to Chevalley's Theorem saying that the image of a constructible set by a morphism of variety is constructible when working over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: «Thanks to Chevalley» not really. At most, «as it follows from a theorem of Chevalley». It would not hurt to make explicit *what* theorem of Chevalley you have in mind, as he has maaaaany theorems!

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652314/why-is-the-image-of-an-algebraic-group-by-a-morphism-also-an-algebraic-group/1662804#1662804. You also haven't responded to my answer to your other question!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks Alex, I'll answer now then.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I am sorry but the answer doesn't help me, since I don't even see what's happening for the image of the map $x\mapsto x^p-x$.